# Ninja on Windows: Expose filename of file in #define

Tags: windows, cmake, ninja

I'm working on a cross-platform project where we build multiple libraries with CMake on Linux, macOS and Windows.

On our POSIX (Linux/macOS) builds we use a simple define in CMake:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -DFILENAME='\"$(notdir $<)\"'")
```

`notdir` is actually a feature of `make`. Unfortunately there is no `make` equivalent on Windows and we are using [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) to build our Windows-based builds.

Is there a similar way to expose the `FILENAME` for our Windows-based builds? I checked the [Ninja Manual](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html) but I could not find a solution.

Switching to MSBuild is not an option because we rely on the `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_LAUNCHER`-feature to preprocess the code for some builds (mostly C89 compatibility).